# How may this question be asked here: Is God male and female? | BH?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

How may this question be asked here: [Is God male and female? | BH?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/11397/is-god-male-and-female)
I tried to but was unsuccessful. The MODs may do well to make available the history to facilitate a better discussion.

---

**Without knowing** that it was posted over at BH, I tried to ask this question at C.SE.. I even set up a chat with I believe @fredsbend. If my memory serves me correct, it was @DavidStratton who closed it. I do not recall the exact reasoning.

I am trying to find out where I may have gone wrong in posing the question and looking for how I might asked it better, hence this META post.

Comment: If the question has already been asked on BH, why do you want to ask here? What would you do differently?

Comment: @JonEricson, Posting the question from a non-hermeneutics (**text** ual analysis) point of view.

Comment: @JonEricson Hence the META post.

Comment: I'm voting to keep this open, but until a link shows up, this is a rather unclear question. I'm guessing the question was deleted? **Any mods that are reading this**, please recover the question FMS is referring to.

Comment: @fredsbend Thanks for the edit. Do you have a link to our chat?

Comment: @Mr.Beatitude Thanks. PS It went through multiple edits in attempts to keep it open but none were successful. A discussion and suggestions here may help me figure what else I could have done.

Comment: @FMS Gee, I don't remember having a chat about this. Sorry.

Comment: @fredsbend And you do not remember me attempting to ask a similar question on C.SE?

Comment: @FMS I think I remember that, but nothing specific.